# Persisting user settings in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am currently writing a Powershell module that I can use to control some smart light bulbs. A requirement for the API is that I provide an authorization token with each request. I currently have a cmdlet `Set-AuthorizationToken` that sets a `$Script:` scoped variable to store this token.

Currently all of the setting functionality I have created exists in the same light automation module. I would like to separate the settings logic into its own module so it can be reused.

This is where I run into trouble. To my knowledge, if I pull the settings logic into its own module then I would no longer be able to use the `$Script:` scope as that would be shared with any module that consumes the settings module. Additionally I would have to refactor the current settings functionality to some provide some sort of identifier so the settings module can look up the correct settings for the caller.

Is there some way that I can create the settings module so I can reuse it, but maybe load it in a manner that allows it to only know about the module that loads it? Maybe like a "library" of some sort? I would prefer not to copy the ps1 files into each module but currently that seems like the best way.

Comment: If you have `PSModuleInfo` object, which represent target module to load settings to, then you can populate `$Script:` scope variables in it with something like this: `& $Module { $Script:Settings = $args[0] } $PersistentSettings`.

Answer (score 2):

The typical way to handle this seems to be to store your credentials as an encrypted string in a file and then have a function for loading those credentials.

For example: https://github.com/RamblingCookieMonster/PSSlack/blob/master/PSSlack/Public/Get-PSSlackConfig.ps1

Comment: That's pretty much what I have now. I was hoping there might be a way to do something much like a dll that might load a file from the applications root directory. But from my research thus far, have seen such a thing unless i porvide the module with a path on every call to it.